# Moving layered windows concurrently in win32

Tags: c++, winapi

i am trying to implement a custom tab control in my win32 window, for that i have used a layered window which is child of the main app window (for the main tab control) and independent windows for individual tab items.

My problem: Whenever i move the main app window, the control window moves along with it (because its the child window) where as the individual tab item windows remain on their position. Can anyone guide me how to to get the tab items windows move along with the main app window concurrently? I can not set the item windows as child of the app, so please base your suggestions on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should redesign your tab to be a child window. Otherwise your attempts to make it work is nothing but a desperate try to fix the thing made bad in first place.

Still if you feel like sticking the original plan, you need to hook/subclass the main app window and handle its movement and sizing messages (`WM_MOVING` and friends) so that your handler could update your popup/tab window position respectively.

Comment: Actually i am using layered window for the tab items; and according to msdn, (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543(v=vs.85).aspx) i can not specify the window as child if it is a layered window. This layer just has to be independent..
Thanks though!I'l look into your second suggestion. I am using an MFC window for my main window, and i cant locate where the WindPorc() method is.
Sorry for my lame questions, im a total newbie at win32 programming and im not allowed to use all features of MFC.

Comment: I am afraid you did not read my answer the way I wanted it sound. It was like this: you SHOULD NOT use layered windows, you SHOULD use child windows instead. As for `WndProc`, every window has it, and having a handle is sufficient for subclassing through `SetWindowLong` and `GWL_WNDPROC`. It is still your choice if you prefer to go this wrong way.

Comment: I need the events transferred to main control window if they are clicked somewhere not desired. And the only way this could be achieved was with layered windows..
I have found where to capture the sizing event, Thanks for your help!